# javascript inside body not working but working without body

Tags: javascript, document-body

Below code works perfectly without  tag. But same is not working within body tag. Please help me to work within body tag.

```
<div id="point1" STYLE="position:absolute;visibility:visible;z-index:1000">
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr><td>
<a href='image/ddaward.gif'>
<img src="image/ddaward.gif" width=96 height=60 alt="" border="0"></a>            
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
<center><a href="http://www.medisystems.in">
<font face="Arial" size="2" color="#0000FF">C.R. Medisystems</font>
</a></center></td></tr></table>
```

```
<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript1.2">

var XX=20; // X position of the scrolling objects
var xstep=1;
var delay_time=60;


var YY=0;  
var ch=0;
var oh=0;
var yon=0;

var ns4=document.layers?1:0
var ie=document.all?1:0
var ns6=document.getElementById&&!document.all?1:0

if(ie){
YY=document.body.clientHeight;
point1.style.top=YY;
}
else if (ns4){
YY=window.innerHeight;
document.point1.pageY=YY;
document.point1.visibility="hidden";
}
    else if (ns6){
    YY=window.innerHeight
    document.getElementById('point1').style.top=YY
  }


function reloc1()
{

if(yon==0){YY=YY-xstep;}
else{YY=YY+xstep;}
if (ie){
    ch=document.body.clientHeight;
    oh=point1.offsetHeight;
    }
    else if (ns4){
    ch=window.innerHeight;
    oh=document.point1.clip.height;
}
    else if (ns6){
    ch=window.innerHeight
    oh=document.getElementById("point1").offsetHeight
    }

    if(YY<0){yon=1;YY=0;}
if(YY>=(ch-oh)){yon=0;YY=(ch-oh);}
if(ie){
    point1.style.left=XX;
    point1.style.top=YY+document.body.scrollTop;
    }
    else if (ns4){
    document.point1.pageX=XX;
    document.point1.pageY=YY+window.pageYOffset;
    }
else if (ns6){
    document.getElementById("point1").style.left=XX
    document.getElementById("point1").style.top=YY+window.pageYOffset
    }

}

function onad()
        {
            if(ns4)
            document.point1.visibility="visible";
            loopfunc();
        }
function loopfunc()
        {
        reloc1();
        setTimeout('loopfunc()',delay_time);
    }

    if (ie||ns4||ns6)
    window.onload=onad

 </script>
```

But this same code for floating image is not working within body tag

```
<html lang="en">
        <head> </head>
        <body>


     <div id="point1" STYLE="position:absolute;visibility:visible;z-
    index:1000">

         <a href='image/ddaward.gif'>
     <img src="image/ddaward.gif" width=96 height=60 alt=""   border="0">
        </a>

        <center><a href="http://www.medisystems.in">

     <font face="Arial" size="2" color="#0000FF">C.R. Medisystems</font>
        </a></center>

        </div>

        <script LANGUAGE="JavaScript1.2">



            var XX=20; // X position of the scrolling objects
            var xstep=1;
            var delay_time=60;

          //Begin of the unchangable area, please do not modify this area
           var YY=0;  
           var ch=0;
           var oh=0;
           var yon=0;

           var ns4=document.layers?1:0
           var ie=document.all?1:0
           var ns6=document.getElementById&&!document.all?1:0

        if(ie){
            YY=document.body.clientHeight;
            point1.style.top=YY;
          }
            else if (ns4){
             YY=window.innerHeight;
            document.point1.pageY=YY;
            document.point1.visibility="hidden";
           }
            else if (ns6){
              YY=window.innerHeight
             document.getElementById('point1').style.top=YY
            }


            function reloc1()
               {

              if(yon==0){YY=YY-xstep;}
              else{YY=YY+xstep;}
                if (ie){
                  ch=document.body.clientHeight;
                  oh=point1.offsetHeight;
               }
                 else if (ns4){
                    ch=window.innerHeight;
                    oh=document.point1.clip.height;
                }
                else if (ns6){
                   ch=window.innerHeight
                  oh=document.getElementById("point1").offsetHeight
             }

              if(YY<0){yon=1;YY=0;}
               if(YY>=(ch-oh)){yon=0;YY=(ch-oh);}
                 if(ie){
                     point1.style.left=XX;
                     point1.style.top=YY+document.body.scrollTop;
                    }
                     else if (ns4){
                          document.point1.pageX=XX;
                         document.point1.pageY=YY+window.pageYOffset;
                      }
                       else if (ns6){
                         document.getElementById("point1").style.left=XX
                document.getElementById("point1").style.top=YY+window.pageYOffset
                }

             }

              function onad()
                 {
                  if(ns4)
                   document.point1.visibility="visible";
                  loopfunc();
                  }
              function loopfunc()
                  {
                    reloc1();
                   setTimeout('loopfunc()',delay_time);
                 }

              if (ie||ns4||ns6)
                 window.onload=onad

              </script>


        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: 1. Welcome to the 21st century. Your code is from 1999. 2. Please urgently visit https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help and fix your question. for example click the ´<>´ button and create a snippet in a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a cleaner version

I removed all code from 2000 (NS4 is 1997, NS6 is 2000) and use addEventlListener instead of window.onload

I extracted inline CSS into a stylesheet

Using the addEventListener AND accessing the DOM in there instead of having an inline document.getElementById is the reason my code will work no matter where in the document you place it

```js
var XX = 20; // X position of the scrolling objects
var xstep = 1;
var delay_time = 60;

//Begin of the unchangable area, please do not modify this area
var YY = 0;
var ch = 0;
var oh = 0;
var yon = 0;

YY = window.innerHeight


function reloc() {
  var point1 = document.getElementById("point1");

  if (yon == 0) {
    YY = YY - xstep;
  } else {
    YY = YY + xstep;
  }
  ch = window.innerHeight;
  oh = point1.offsetHeight;

  if (YY < 0) {
    yon = 1;
    YY = 0;
  }
  if (YY >= (ch - oh)) {
    yon = 0;
    YY = (ch - oh);
  }
  var top = YY + window.pageYOffset;
  point1.style.left = XX + "px";
  point1.style.top = top + "px";

}

window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  var point1 = document.getElementById('point1');
  point1.style.top = YY + "px";
  point1.visibility = "visible";
  setInterval(reloc, delay_time);
})
```

```css
#point1 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #0000FF;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="point1">
  <a href='image/ddaward.gif'><img 
    src="https://woodhousevideoproduction.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/DDAWards-200x200.jpg" width=96 height=60 alt="" border="0" />
  </a><br/>
  <a href="http://www.medisystems.in">C.R. Medisystems</a>
</div>
```

Comment: where should i put script part . i have put in body part but its not working. i have also put in head part. please tell me how should i put code in html and body.

Comment: You need to put it inside `<script></script>` tags without the language attibute and the code you posted is testing Netscape 4 (1997) and Netscape 6 (2000)

Comment: You can put my code anywhere you want - head or body.

Comment: Please see my update - I externalised the inline style. You can have that in `<style></style>` or in `<link src="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />`

Comment: My issue is solved thanks. but i wanted to know why it was not working.

Comment: Hard to tell exactly. Any inline code accessing a form element has to wait until the element exists